# How to combine two mp3 file parallely in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing a music application for Windows Phone 8. I will have two mp3 files. My requirement is to combine two mp3 files together. The user should hear the music as if both the mp3 is playing parallely. But it should be a single mp3 playing, since we will combine two mp3 into one. So i want to know the following:

1. how to combine two mp3, so that the user feels like hearing two mp3 in parallel?

Comment: http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://sox.sourceforge.net/

sox.exe -m fileone.mp3 filetwo.mp3 output.mp3

Sox doesn't have support for mp3s so you need to download this version which has those references compiled into the executable. Additionally you can search for the dll and the latest should pick them up.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Compiling_SOX_with_Lame.aspx

Use a Process class to call this from .Net.